# Exception thrown in SurfaceImageSource.as()

Tags: directx, c++-winrt, winui-3

I'm back to C++ after a 31-year absence and have spent the last few months learning everything I can about Windows app development, UWP, C++/WinRT, DirectX, WinUI 3, XAML, etc.  All within Visual Studio 2022 Community.

I'm currently working on creating an app template that brings together DirectX and WinUI 3, allowing me to draw on a surface within XAML/UI3.  So far I've been able to create separate apps with each component (modifying existing Microsoft templates), but I'm struggling a bit bringing them all together.

The closest example I've found (using C++/WinRT) is the "[DirectX and XAML interop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop)" tutorial.  I copied the example into my WinUI 3 project and it compiles no errors and the UI runs fine until I click on the button that invokes the tutorial code.  Then it crashes trying to create a winrt::com_ptr to the SurfaceImageSource.  I've spent a couple of days now trying to figure out why.  The code in question is :

```
(C++/WinRT)

    SurfaceImageSource  surfaceImageSource( 500, 500 ) ;
    
    winrt :: com_ptr <::ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D> sisNativeWithD2D { 
                    surfaceImageSource.as <::ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D> () } ;
```

If I replace "surfaceImageSource.as" with "surfaceImageSource.try_as" the call returns, but .get() on the com_ptr returns nullptr.  So it looks like internally, QueryInterface is not succeeding.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated since I don't know where to go from here.
Thanks.

*** EDIT *** :  additional information added per IInspectable's comment

Thanks IInspectable for your help.  I can reproduce this with the following minimal setup :

1 - Create a new project from "Blank App, Packaged (WinUI 3 in Desktop)" C++/WinRT template.  This project creates a blank window with a UI3 "Click Me" button in its center.

2 - In the file "MainWindow.xaml.cpp" :

a - at the top, add :

```
#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>

#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>

using namespace winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;
```

b -  further down, in the method "MainWindow::myButton_Click()" add the two lines mentioned earlier :

```
SurfaceImageSource  surfaceImageSource(500, 500);

winrt::com_ptr <::ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D> sisNativeWithD2D{
                surfaceImageSource.as <::ISurfaceImageSourceNativeWithD2D>() };
```

3 - that's it.  Rebuild and the program crashes on the button click.

I put a breakpoint between the two lines above.
I then put another breakpoint in "Generated Files\winrt\base.h" on first line of "struct IUnknown :: as()":

```
template <typename To>
auto as() const
{ (breakpoint here)

    return impl::as<To>(m_ptr);
}
```

When I continue execution, the program crashes immediately before returning to the next line of myButton_Click() (as far as I can determine).

Debug Output

```
'My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsAppRuntime.1.1_1004.584.2120.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Microsoft.DirectManipulation.dll'. 
onecoreuap\windows\frameworkudk\dxprivatescommon.cpp(53)\Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll!00007FFFABE09BC5: (caller: 00007FFFABE5ED0D) ReturnHr(1) tid(2508) 80004002 This interface is not supported
onecoreuap\windows\frameworkudk\dxprivatescommon.cpp(53)\Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll!00007FFFABE09BC5: (caller: 00007FFFABE5ED0D) ReturnHr(2) tid(2508) 80004002 This interface is not supported
onecoreuap\windows\frameworkudk\dxprivatescommon.cpp(53)\Microsoft.Internal.FrameworkUdk.dll!00007FFFABE09BC5: (caller: 00007FFFABE5ED0D) ReturnHr(3) tid(3670) 80004002 This interface is not supported
'My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cabinet.dll'. 
'My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\XamlDiagnostics\x64\WinUI3\Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WinUITap.dll'. 
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll!00007FFF8DAF3D45: (caller: 00007FFF90651CAF) ReturnHr(1) tid(2508) 80070057 Incorrect parameter.
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll!00007FFF8DAF3D45: (caller: 00007FFF90651CAF) ReturnHr(2) tid(2508) 80070057 Incorrect parameter.
Microsoft.UI.Xaml.dll!00007FFF8DAF3D45: (caller: 00007FFF90651CAF) ReturnHr(3) tid(2508) 80070057 Incorrect parameter.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF83C644FD9 (KernelBase.dll) in My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe: WinRT originate error - 0x80004002 : 'This interface is not supported'.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF83C644FD9 in My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: winrt::hresult_no_interface at memory location 0x0000005C234FA538.
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF83C644FD9 in My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: [rethrow] at memory location 0x0000000000000000.
A breakpoint instruction (__debugbreak() statement or a similar call) was executed in My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe.
```

Call Stack

```
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::My_WinUI_3_project_4::implementation::App::{ctor}::__l2::<lambda>(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable & __formal, const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::UnhandledExceptionEventArgs & e) Line 31 C++
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::impl::delegate<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::UnhandledExceptionEventHandler,void <lambda>(const winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable &, const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::UnhandledExceptionEventArgs &)>::Invoke(void * sender, void * e) Line 4824  C++
[External Code] 
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::impl::consume_Microsoft_UI_Xaml_IApplicationStatics<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics>::Start(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback & callback) Line 157    C++
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start::__l2::<lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics & f) Line 12146   C++
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::impl::factory_cache_entry<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics>::call<void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) &>(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start::__l2::void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) & callback) Line 6286   C++
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::impl::call_factory<winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application,winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics,void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &)>(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start::__l2::void <lambda>(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::IApplicationStatics &) && callback) Line 6309  C++
My_WinUI_3_project_4.exe!winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Application::Start(const winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::ApplicationInitializationCallback & callback) Line 12147  C++
[External Code]
```

Comment: [`com_ptr::as`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/cpp-ref-for-winrt/com-ptr#com_ptras-function) is a wrapper around [`QueryInterface`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl/queryinterface). If it fails, the object doesn't implement the interface you are requesting. You'll need to provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This:

#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>

should be this:

#include <microsoft.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>

when working with WinUI 3.0 Desktop apps and not UWP.

Comment: Thank you Hemofelicity.  That was all that was needed.
I can now draw to a surface with Direct2D/3D within my XAML window amongst the other WinUI 3 controls (you made my day).
I had spent some time trying to figure out if I should be using the Microsoft namespace or the Windows namespace and never found an answer though your comment led me to the Windows App SDK namespaces page which helps.  Look like Microsoft when possible, Windows otherwise ? (Windows.UI.h still seems to be necesssary for Color even though there is a Microsoft.UI.h).

Comment: Yes. The color struct to use is still the one from Windows.UI.h. Also note, there are API's, those not relating to UI, like <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>, that remain under the Windows namespace.

Comment: The easiest way to find anything under the Microsoft namespace is to navigate these pages https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1 or look up including the key words Microsoft UI Xaml.