# C++ set Image Source() from SurfaceImageSource doesn't compile (from learn.microsoft example)

Tags: xaml, directx, winui-3

I try to reproduce the SurfaceImageSource example of Direct2D using XAML Image :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop

And I have a compilation error at this line :

`theImage().Source(surfaceImageSource);`

The Source expect a reference to ImageSource, but it doesn't compile for me when I provide a SurfaceImageSource, like on the example.

Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls::Image::Source" matches the argument list

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Minimal code :

On the XML file :

`<Image x:Name="theImage" Width="500" Height="500" />`

On the cpp file

```
    void MainWindow::myButton_Click(IInspectable const&, RoutedEventArgs const&)
    {
        myButton().Content(box_value(L"Clicked"));

        SurfaceImageSource surfaceImageSource(500, 500);
        theImage().Source(surfaceImageSource); // -> FAIL here
    }
```

Comment: This sample is for UWP not WinUI3. However they are similar, do you have a fully reproducing problem? Anything could be wrong w/o a single piece of code shown. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Simon for the hint about UWP example used in WinUI3. And for this link which started to help me but was not complete :
[Exception thrown in SurfaceImageSource.as()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73493777/exception-thrown-in-surfaceimagesource-as)

Solution :

In pch.h replace

```
#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>
```

by

```
#include <windows.ui.xaml.media.dxinterop.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.h>
```

And in the .cpp file replace :

```
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;
```

by

```
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging;
```